# Handle push notification when app is running and notification tray is opened

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

While trying to implement FCM in my iOS app, I came across this issue. I have my app **opened**, at the same time I slide down the **Notification tray** of my device. When I send a push notification, my application state prints as **INACTIVE** (which is correct since the tray comes in foreground, leaving my app in the background)

I am loading a URL on notification tap, hence when user slides up the tray, the url is directly loaded and **no notification is displayed** in the tray.

In this scenario, I wish to display notification in the tray and open URL only when the user taps on the notification. Is there any way to detect if the Notification tray is **visible over my app specifically**?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Third party library : https://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner  or you can show alert by handling if app is in foreground or inactive state in notification recieving delegate.